# Using a Handler to pass Object to the UI thread in order to make some UI updates

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I have this client class "T_Client" in a client-server implementation
**T_Client:**

```java
public class T_Client{
    private static final String TAG = "T_Client";

    private static String serverIP = "192.168.2.5";
    private static int port = 4444;
    private InetAddress serverAddr = null;
    private Socket sock = null;
    private boolean running = false;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    Object objIn;    

    public void send(MessageCustom _msg) {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.writeObject(_msg);
                out.flush();

                // out.close();
                Log.i("Send Method", "Outgoing : " + _msg.toString());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("Send Method", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        running = true;
        try {
            // here you must put your computer's IP address.
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);

            Log.i("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            // create a socket to make the connection with the server
            sock = new Socket(serverAddr, port);

            try {

                // send the message to the server
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

                // receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

                Log.i("TCP Client", "C: Connected.");

                // in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the
                // server
                while (running) {
                    objIn = in.readObject();

                    Log.i("Object Read", objIn.toString());

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + objIn
                        + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                // the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to
                // this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to
                // be created.
                out.close();
                in.close();
                sock.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Closing socket: " + sock);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

}
```

And I want to get the Object from the server(objIn) and pass it to the UI thread so I can do some UI updates there. From searching around a bit, I think that I have to use a Handler, but can't really wrap my head around the implementation.
Could someone give me a simple example of how to implement a handler in my case, and make the call in a Main Activity? Or point me to a simple tutorial to get me started, cause I've tried to follow the one over at the Android Developers site but it's too complicated.

Comment: just use handler.sendMessage(msg) where msg  = handler.obtainMessage(...)

Comment: Coul you plz give me an example?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=handler.obtainMessage+tutorial&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr